# Analytical demonstration of the equivalence of the two methods

Tags: solution-verification, physics, python

I'm trying to resolve this exercise:

> Prove that the two ways of sampling of the step length $s$ employed by Geant4 and Penelope are equivalent. In other words, demonstrate that sampling the individual step lenghts $s_i$ from $\displaystyle \mu_i e^{−\mu_i s_i}$ and then taking $s = min\{s_1 . . . s_N \}$ is the same as sampling $s$ from $\mu e^{\mu s}$ , with $\mu =\sum_i \mu_i$.

I already verified the equivalence using a code in python (that i delete from the post as suggested). I obtained this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ewjje.png).

Now i want to demostrate this equivalence analitically.

How can i do that? Any hint?

Comment: Please delete all of the computer code from your question.  If you have a mathematical question as to why two distinct formulas either do or don't yield the same results, or the expected results, then mathSE is the right place.  If you are looking for someone to sift through computer code, then mathSE is the wrong place.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Thanks guys, i deleted the code and edite the post (now i'm re-writing it using MathJax).